# I have a css navigation bar with three items. I want to make each link show its own content without overlapping the other one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

Here is what I have so far, which works fine, but doesn't disappear once another link is activated.

```js
function skillsFunction () {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySkills");
    if (x.style.display == "none"){
     x.style.display = "block"; {}
    } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
    } 
}
        
let openTab = (event, tabNumber) => {
    const tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");
    
    for(let tab of tabContent) {
     tab.style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(tabNumber).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab" onclick="openTab(event,1)">Projects</span>
    <span class="tab" onclick="openTab(event,2)">Skills</span>
    <span class="tab" onclick="openTab(event,3)">Courses</span>
</div>

<div class="mySkills" id="2"></div>
<div class="myCourses" id="3"></div>
<!--START OF PROJECTS WRAPPER-->
<div class="projectsWrapper" id="1">
```

This is my first time using JavaScript.

Comment: are you using jQery ?

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, first off it is typically not good practice to use HTML `onclick=""` to handle clicks, so we would rather use JS to attach an event listener.

In the HTML, add the class of `tabContent`, which was missing, an `id` to each tab, and add `"div" + tabId` to each body content (Ids can be whatever you want just keep them the same). Also add `display:none` to initially start the content closed (probably choose one to start open and leave that without `display:none`) (And of course change the layout/whatever to fit the rest of your HTML):

Then, in the JS initialize tabs and tabContent, and for each tab add a click event listener which hides every tabContent then displays the one that matches the tabId.

```js
    const tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    const tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");

    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      tabs[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        for(var i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
          tabContent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
  
        var tabId = event.target.id;
        document.getElementById("div" + tabId).style.display = "block";
      });
    }
```

```html
    <span id="PROJECTS" class="tab">Projects</span>
    <span id="SKILLS" class="tab">Skills</span>
    <span id="COURSES" class="tab">Courses</span>
    
    <div class="mySkills tabContent" id="divSKILLS" style="display:none">
      Skills
    </div>
    <div class="myCourses tabContent" id="divCOURSES" style="display:none">
      Courses
    </div>
    <div class="projectsWrapper tabContent" id="divPROJECTS" style="display:none">
      Projects
    </div>
```

Let me know how it goes!

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Maxmaxs5/dxyrk4o8/14/)